# Retrieve selected list item title

Tags: splistitem

Is there a way to retrieve the selected list item title/name? For example if I click an item say "Distributor" in custom list, how can I get this title in a string or variable?

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean doing it through code you could use the [getSelectedItems()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff409526.aspx) method:

```
var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
```

You could then just iterate through the items and get the desired attribute:

```
for(i in items) 
{ 
 // do something
}
```

[Here is an example of it in use](http://tomaszrabinski.pl/wordpress/2012/02/25/get-selected-list-items-sharepoint-2010/)

Comment: This is the only approach. There is no equivalent to this method on the server side as the selection is completely done client side in SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CAML and [SPQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.aspx):

```
private SPListCollection GetDecriptionItems(SPList list)
{
  SPQuery query = new SPQuery()
  {
    Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Distributor'></Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy>"
  };
  return list.GetItems(query);
}
```